# Doctrine join 4 entities and order by datetime

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine

I would like to join 4 entities that each have upload_datetime column. Then i would like to order them by that datetime column descending and get only 7 records.

Right now i have this:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT a,v,p,q FROM SelfInspirationDomainBundle:Articles a, SelfInspirationDomainBundle:Videos v, SelfInspirationDomainBundle:Pictures p,SelfInspirationDomainBundle:Quotes q ORDER BY a.uploadDatetime DESC, v.uploadDatetime DESC, p.uploadDatetime DESC, q.uploadDatetime DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getResult();
```

But it doesn't seem to work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need to implement a UNION rather than a JOIN

Comment: What, exactly, precisely, does 'it doesn't seem to work correctly' mean ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a parent class to encapsulate the shared functionality and use Doctrine's [Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) to create a sub-class for each of those four classes.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Artice", "video" = "Video", ...})
 */
class Asset
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="upload_datetime", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $upload_datetime;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article extends Asset {
...
}
```

Then you can do a query like:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT a FROM Bundle:Asset a ORDER by a.update_datetime');
```